# AngularJS: What filter type may I use to create custom currency directive?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an input form that takes currency values in the hundreds, millions, billions etc. To make it user-friendly I'd like those custom input fields to show and let the user input e.g. '1.5M' instead of 1500000, '1B' instead of 1000000000 and so on. For that purpose I created a `FormatServices` service with two methods `currParse(value: string): number` and `currFormat(value: number): string` and they do what they are supposed to i.e. transform between model and display values and back.

Now I define a custom currency directive as follows:

```
.directive("currency", function($filter, formatServices: FormatServices){
    // convert to number
    var p = function(viewValue){
        if (angular.isDefined(viewValue)) {
            return $filter('number')(formatServices.currParse(viewValue));
        }
    };

    var f = function(modelValue){
        if (angular.isDefined(modelValue)) {
            // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE WHAT FILTER TYPE?
            return $filter('???')(formatServices.currFormat(modelValue));
        }
    };

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl){
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(p);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(f);
        }
    };
})
```

In the annotated line I need a filter type. Looking at the [available filter types in Ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) I tried with `number` but doesn't work because is a string output. `json` filter type works but the output includes double quotes around it. `uppercase` and `lowercase` don't work either because they destroy my format e.g. I can have 100k or 1.5M. There is no `text` filter so I don't know what to fill in there to have this working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you own filter. 
This example make an IntegerCurrency.

```
.filter('myCurrency', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
  return function(input) {
    input = parseFloat(input);
    if(input % 1 === 0) {
      input = input.toFixed(0);
    }
    return '$' + input;
    //you can change $ or € put ',' '.'  '-' or decorate whate ever the output.
  };
}])
```